# Adjust Iframe height for IE11 with Document modes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm Using IE11, Edge Document mode, Windows render the iframe height differently.
I was using this before.

```
<iframe name="stack" src="http://stackoverflow.com/" width='100%' height='100%' frameborder="0" id="iframe">...</iframe>
```

IE shrinks the Iframe to only a few lines tall, the width attribute works normally, but not the height. So I added style attribute to it and now the height is also working fine.

```
<iframe name="stack" src="http://stackoverflow.com/" style='height: 100%; width: 100%;' frameborder="0" id="iframe">...</iframe>
```

But in debug mode, when I switch to different document mode the iframe height screws up again. Is there a javascript we can use to render the frames height according to the window's height for all document modes.?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. I guess you did not stretch body height to `100%`.

```
html, body { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```